# Django 1.3: __file__ contains wrong value (path to different app)

Tags: python, django, filepath

I am using Django 1.3 (yes, I know about the end of support) on Python 2.6.

Some files named `blocks.py` in apps are loaded dynamically on runtime, something along:

```
if foo:
    # load apps/foo/blocks.py,
    # of course with correct call to load_module
    imp.load_module('foo.blocks')
if bar:
    # load apps/bar/blocks.py
    imp.load_module('bar.blocks')
```

The settings.py has both apps `foo` and `bar` loaded:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ( 'foo', 'bar' )
```

Now, I have the peculiar behavior, that a call to `__file__` in `apps/bar/blocks.py` shows *sometimes* a wrong value, specifically

```
/docroot/apps/foo/blocks.pyc
              ^---- this should be "bar"
```

"Sometimes" means, the first request for my Django instance works just fine, but all subsequent requests show this behavior.

I used `__file__` before, in other apps as well, but never noticed this strange bug. My theory is, that it's somehow related to the dynamic importing of the modules, but I can't lay my finger on what could be the deeper issue.

**What can be the reason, that `__file__` in one Python file shows, wrongly, the value for another Python file?**

Comment: Are the `foo`/`bar` mutual? (loaded question: is it possible that both foo and bar have been loaded). I feel your pain about django 1.3... but are you using the most recent minor version of that?

Comment: Yes, it is common, that both modules are loaded at the same time. Think components, that are imported on request/use. The most recent minor version seems to be 1.3.7. I haven't used this, but try, if updating changes something.

Comment: By the way, I suspect something similar like what is described here: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200904/running_a_python_file_as_main.html. However, I already _do_ use `imp.load_module`, and I checked the content of the `*.pyc` files, that is correct. So it's not the exact same issue.

Comment: OK, tested it. No change with 1.3.7, the problem persists.

Comment: Hmm... I'm afraid I'm not going to be able to offer much more pointers here (Same again with latest py2.6 of course). My thought on your actual question at the end is that it isn't looking on a module level and hence just looks in some sort of cache for most recent values, no idea about going on to fix this though if it even were correct.

Comment: Thanks anyway! Time for me to dig deeper into Python's module loading...